# angular repeat with template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, requirejs

I'm currently trying to figure out how to use templates in angular. At present, I'm playing with ui.router (angular-ui-router) but I can't find good documentation on how the templating language is used to embed a sub-template view, especially as relates to a repeating element for different model instances.

BACKGROUND:

I am basically converting a static-local-filesystem image uploader/manager to work with amazon S3.  The background essentials are already worked out, now I'm trying to improve the UI itself by converting it from 10 year old javascript to angular.js. I have it 'working' for an all-in-one html page but would prefer to modularize it to make it more dynamic.

CONTEXT:

I get a list of objects under a given prefix back from a listObjectsV2() call to the AWS sdk via the s3 client. I parse the results to break it into a pseudo-directory tree then display one directory at a time starting at the [virtual] root dir just after the prefix. (FYI the prefix is a userid)

I built a UserDir object that uses a PseudoDir sub object to define a virtual directory with array properties for 'subdirs' (more PseudoDir objects representing virtual sub-directories) and 'images' (S3 objects that are image files of one type or another).

What I want to display for any given 'current' directory (e.g. "" or the user root) is first a list of folder icons for each the curDir.subdirs, then a thumbnail icon for each of the curDir.images.

[image: image uploader]

QUESTION:
I already have this working from a single html file and even managed to figured out how to use ui.router to create a  for the main page. Now I want to modularize it so that a different controller will handle folder icon/info behavior, and another for image icons/behaviors.

i.e. I have already started building a 'FolderController' and a 'ImageController' and would like the ngRepeat for 'image in curDir.images' for example, to invoke a state with it's own template but I can't seem to find an example on how to do that.

Here is the current all-in-one template code.  But I would like to move each sub-block into a state for FolderController with a templates/folder.html template and one for ImageController with a templates/image.html but can't seem to find an example of how to write the syntax:

```
        <!-- folders -->
        <div ng-repeat="(folder, pDir) in subdirs" ng-controller="FolderController" ng-init="folderName=folder;awsObject=pDir">
            <div id="{{folderName}}" class="Item">
                <div class="Icon ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
                    <img id="{{folderName}}Icon" src="../../images/folder.png">
                </div>
                <div id="{{folderName}}Desc" class="Description">
                    <span id="{{folderName}}Name" class="filename" title="{{folderName}}/">{{folderName}}/</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- images -->
        <div ng-repeat="(filename, uImage) in images" ng-controller="ImageController" ng-init="uImage=uImage">
            <div id="image{{uImage.hash}}" class="Item">
                <div class="Icon ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
                    <img id="icon{{uImage.hash}}" ng-src="{{ uImage.thumbSrc }}"></div>
                <div id="desc{{uImage.hash}}" class="Description">
                    <span id="name{{uImage.hash}}" class="filename" title="{{filename}}">{{filename}}</span>
                    <img id="thumb{{uImage.hash}}" src="../../images/tick_image-services.png" class="Check Right" ng-show="uImage.usedInLayout" title="Used in layout"><br />
                    <span id="date{{uImage.hash}}" ng-show="(uImage.mtime > 0)">Date uploaded: {{ uImage.mtime | date: 'EEE MMM dd yyyy' }}</span><br />
                    <span id="size{{uImage.hash}}" ng-show="(uImage.size > 0)">Size: {{ uImage.size | humanizeBytes }}</span><br />
                    <span id="dims{{uImage.hash}}" ng-show="((uImage.width > 0) && (uImage.height > 0))">Dimensions: {{ uImage.width }} x {{ uImage.height }} pixels</span><br />
                    <span id="aspect{{uImage.hash}}" ng-show="(uImage.aspectRatio)">Aspect Ratio: <span class="AspectRatio">{{ uImage.aspectRatio }}</span></span><br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two components, one for folders and one for images, see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) for official docs.

A rough draft would look like:

```
angular.module('myApp').component('images', {
  templateUrl: 'imageList.html',
  bindings: {
    images: '='
  }
});
```

imageList.html:

```
<div ng-repeat="(filename, uImage) in images" ng-controller="ImageController" ng-init="uImage=uImage">
            <div id="image{{uImage.hash}}" class="Item">
                <div class="Icon ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
                    <img id="icon{{uImage.hash}}" ng-src="{{ uImage.thumbSrc }}"></div>
                <div id="desc{{uImage.hash}}" class="Description">
                    <span id="name{{uImage.hash}}" class="filename" title="{{filename}}">{{filename}}</span>
                    <img id="thumb{{uImage.hash}}" src="../../images/tick_image-services.png" class="Check Right" ng-show="uImage.usedInLayout" title="Used in layout"><br />
                    <span id="date{{uImage.hash}}" ng-show="(uImage.mtime > 0)">Date uploaded: {{ uImage.mtime | date: 'EEE MMM dd yyyy' }}</span><br />
                    <span id="size{{uImage.hash}}" ng-show="(uImage.size > 0)">Size: {{ uImage.size | humanizeBytes }}</span><br />
                    <span id="dims{{uImage.hash}}" ng-show="((uImage.width > 0) && (uImage.height > 0))">Dimensions: {{ uImage.width }} x {{ uImage.height }} pixels</span><br />
                    <span id="aspect{{uImage.hash}}" ng-show="(uImage.aspectRatio)">Aspect Ratio: <span class="AspectRatio">{{ uImage.aspectRatio }}</span></span><br />
                </div>
            </div>
```

and your original html would look like:

```
<!-- folders -->
<div ng-repeat="(folder, pDir) in subdirs" ng-controller="FolderController" ng-init="folderName=folder;awsObject=pDir">
    <div id="{{folderName}}" class="Item">
        <div class="Icon ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
            <img id="{{folderName}}Icon" src="../../images/folder.png">
        </div>
        <div id="{{folderName}}Desc" class="Description">
            <span id="{{folderName}}Name" class="filename" title="{{folderName}}/">{{folderName}}/</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<image-list [images]="images" ></image-list>
```

**EDIT**
Here is an [example plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UHFVJERVr3lsoV6O) which shows a simple implementation of a component, with data binding and ng-repeat in it, no need for ui-router for what you asked for. Please note that the html I wrote above is a botched copy paste of what you wrote - so the double ng-repeat was a mistake, updated the html.

Comment: I'm confused looking at that, however, as it seems you have an ng-repeat inside an ng-repeat for the same items.

Comment: binding is not working - I can do {{ images | json }} just outside <image-list> and I see the data fine. Inside the template, it does not show any data

Comment: ahh, I figured out the binding problem. It was actually related to using require.js for AMD since my aws stuff is not angular based. It seems components just set a property on the controller directly, but require.js objects inject $scope into a class property. So require.js objects scope is actually this.$scope but angular was binding the property to this.property instead of this.$scope.property

Comment: I got around that by fudging a $oninit to put the bound properties into $scope after the component's controller is initialized